# LM386 emitting voltage to input line

Tags: pins, damage, lm386

there is around +4mV that emitted by input pin (pin2) to the ground in lm386 my question is:
1. is that normal?
2. will it damage IC audio in laptop ?
3. if (number 2 is yes) then i need to put capacitor between input pin and line out laptop, will it ruin the original audio signal / filter any sound?

Comment: How about showing us your schematic? We're not psychic!  Oh, and people still use the LM386?! I suppose the same people that still use the LM741 :P

Comment: Use a coupling capacitor, probably 0.2 uF or larger is enough. It won't harm the sound quality significantly. After all, if you want high end audio quality, an LM386 is the wrong place to start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LM386 has a PNP darlington input stage with about 250nA of bias current and an input resistance of 50K.

That means typically you could see somewhere around 12.5mV on an open input.  So 4mV isn't out of the question.

If you're driving the input from the line out of your laptop a few mV shouldn't present a problem, though to minimize offset you should tie the unused input to ground through a resistor equal to the output impedance of the source. Capacitor coupling is definitely an option, and if done properly wouldn't have any appreciable effect on the sound, since you wouldn't be reproducing (or hearing) very low frequencies anyway.

Comment: but how much exact capacitor i should use?

Comment: Well you could probably get away with 0.1uF and up. That will give you around 30Hz or lower cutoff.  Remember to use a non-polarized capacitor.

Comment: Can you tell me how to calculate that? And why i should use non polarize capacitor? thank you